# Height issue for nested elements

Tags: html, css

I have nested elements. I have an outer div with the height specified. and an inner table with height as 100%. But the table content is overflowing the outer div

```
 <div class="statistics">
    <table id ="statsTable">
      <tr>
        <th>Team1</th>
        <th>Team2</th>
        <th>Winner</th>
        <th>Win By run</th>
        <th>Win By Wicket</th>
      </tr>
      <tr *ngFor="let item of tableData">
        <td>{{item.team1}}</td>
        <td>{{item.team2}}</td>
        <td>{{item.winner}}</td>
        <td>{{item.win_by_runs}}</td>
        <td>{{item.win_by_wickets}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

my css -

```
    .statistics{
    height:400px;
    }
    #statsTable{
    color:white;
    height: 100%;
    }
```

I want my table to be inside the height specified by outer div

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding an `overflow:auto` to the outer `div`? That will make the table stay inside and scroll when needed.

```css
.statistics {
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: auto;
}

#statsTable {
  /*color:white;*/
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="statistics">
  <table id="statsTable">
    <tr>
      <th>Team1</th>
      <th>Team2</th>
      <th>Winner</th>
      <th>Win By run</th>
      <th>Win By Wicket</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of tableData">
      <td>{{item.team1}}</td>
      <td>{{item.team2}}</td>
      <td>{{item.winner}}</td>
      <td>{{item.win_by_runs}}</td>
      <td>{{item.win_by_wickets}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: please try the snippet i just added

Comment: i have noticed that my div is a flex item, if I remove display:flex from the parent element,it works fine. Is this has to do something with flexbox?

Answer (score 0):

See this codepen https://codepen.io/rensmateyo/pen/oNvjJbQ, `Overflow: auto;` seems to work fine with it